# Secure mount options in Ubuntu CIS benchmarks too narrow?

Tags: linux, server, hardening, file-system, partition

this is the first of a series of questions on hardening Linux servers at the filesystem level.

At work I'm hardening an Ubuntu 18.04 Server following the [CIS benchmark 2.0.1](https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks). Instead of just running a hardening script, I'm doing it manually in order to really understand the process. For the sake of the exercise, I am assuming that the system will be a high-activity enterprise server in a hostile/compromised network, so defense in depth is crucial.

The partitioning scheme recommended by CIS (section 1.1 of the above doc) prescribes adding the following partitions and mount options:

```
/tmp            nodev,nosuid,noexec
/var
/var/tmp        nodev,nosuid,noexec
/var/log
/var/log/audit
/home           nodev
/dev/shm        nodev,nosuid,noexec
[removable]     nodev,nosuid,noexec
```

Why limit `nodev,nosuid,noexec` to `/var/tmp` instead of applying it on `/var` too? I am aware of the reasons for separate partitions, I'm just curious about the mount options.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll look at one example case:
I'm not sure about the nodev part but the journal directory in my /var/log has the setgid bit set which is logging for systemd (replacing syslog).  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html

Comment: @DarkMatter: cool, I didn't think of the implications of setgid. Makes sense. Thanks!